# Delete outdated test ouputs when rerunning tests

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle with the Java plugin.

Is there a way to delete outdated test outputs when rerunning the tests?  (In the folders testReportsDir and testResultsDir)
I see the following possible solutions but I don't know how to configure it:

- Before running the tests delete all test outputs.
- After running the tests delete outdated test output files.

**Background:** 
I only wan't to rerun the testcases when the inputs/outputs have changed. 
Although when rerunning the tests I want to clear the report so that there is no old reports laying around. 
**Example:** If I rename/delete an TestClass123 the testResultsDir would still contain an old xml with the results of the deleted/renamed testclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a workaround you can delete the testresultsDir in a doFirst block:

```
test{
   doFirst{
       delete testResultsDir
   }
}
```

Comment: Won't this cause the tests to always run because the task outputs will have changed? Or is that evaluated before any of the actions?

Comment: No it wouldnt, because the up-to-date check already decided to execute the task or not. The doFirst block is only executed if the task is not up-to-date